# PostgreSQL - Ordering query result by Left-Joined One-To-Many field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently stuck trying to order the results of my query by a left joined field.

The error is: **column "aliases.alias" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**.

Now, I can fix that error by adding a field in the group by: **"aliases.alias"**, but doing so duplicates the results of the query for each alias that series has.

I'm trying to find a way to use **aliases.alias** in my order by statement without duplicating my results.

The search SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    series.id as series.id,
    series."name",
    series."overview",
    series."firstAired",
    CAST(CASE WHEN posters."seriesId" IS NULL THEN false ELSE true END AS BOOLEAN) AS poster,
    FROM series
    LEFT JOIN "posters" ON posters."seriesId" = series.id
    LEFT JOIN "aliases" ON aliases."seriesId" = series.id
    WHERE (series.document @@to_tsquery(:query))
    OR (aliases.document @@to_tsquery(:query))
    GROUP BY series.id, posters."seriesId"
    ORDER BY
        GREATEST(
            ts_rank(series.document, to_tsquery(:query), 8),
            MAX(ts_rank(aliases.document, to_tsquery(:query), 8)),
            similarity(series."name", quote_literal(:query)),
            similarity(aliases."alias", quote_literal(:query))
        )
        DESC
        NULLS LAST;
```

The value of **:query** is the user input.

Here is an image of the related tables and their relations:

[image: Tables and Relations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation function, say:

```
        max(similarity(aliases."alias", quote_literal(:query)))
```